# Можно ли отключить в строках с "логами" дату и время?

Tags: android, android-studio

В окне Logcat хотелось бы видеть только сообщения "логов", без даты и времени.
Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: странный вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно. Нажмите там слева на шестерёнку (*в 3.1. В предыдущих версиях кнопка может быть в другом месте, да и выглядеть по-другому*) и уберите галочку с "дата/время".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]